# Is the soul eager to enter this world?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, soul, contradiction

Is it brought down anywhere that before birth, the soul yearns to be brought into a physical body, and be in this world, and if yes, how do we reconcile that with what it is taught that the soul is reluctant to enter this world?

Comment: I thought it was the reverse, that the neshama wants to go back to its source, and resisted being taken down to this world

Comment: @mbloch Manis Friedman address that in the link [below](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137767/6592). Basically, the natural instinct is to stay where it is, but the realization of what it can accomplish overpowers that. I imagine it's something like the will to get up in the morning.

Comment: Based on what @mbloch says - refer to the famous Medrash Tanchuma - Pekudei 3 - https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Pekudei.3.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%A6%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A1%D6%BB%D7%92%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A9%D6%BC%D7%82%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%94

Comment: תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: שְׁתֵּי שָׁנִים וּמֶחֱצָה נֶחְלְקוּ בֵּית שַׁמַּאי וּבֵית הִלֵּל. הַלָּלוּ אוֹמְרִים: נוֹחַ לוֹ לְאָדָם שֶׁלֹּא נִבְרָא יוֹתֵר מִשֶּׁנִּבְרָא, וְהַלָּלוּ אוֹמְרִים: נוֹחַ לוֹ לְאָדָם שֶׁנִּבְרָא יוֹתֵר מִשֶּׁלֹּא נִבְרָא. נִמְנוּ וְגָמְרוּ: נוֹחַ לוֹ לְאָדָם שֶׁלֹּא נִבְרָא יוֹתֵר מִשֶּׁנִּבְרָא, עַכְשָׁיו שֶׁנִּבְרָא — יְפַשְׁפֵּשׁ בְּמַעֲשָׂיו. וְאָמְרִי לַהּ: יְמַשְׁמֵשׁ בְּמַעֲשָׂיו (עירובין יג:ב).

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, I came across a relevant source in [Hayom Yom](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/hayomyom.asp?tdate=10/30/2023):

> "The soul above eagerly anticipates the moment it can descend into a
> physical body, recognizing the immense potential for achieving a
> connection with God and experiencing profound spiritual joy here on
> Earth. So, what is everyone waiting for?"

In the source, the language is even more explicit. See English Translation [here 20-21](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3150598/jewish/Shabbos-Chol-HaMoed-Pesach-5700-1940-Lakewood-2.htm).